# viewModel with two fragments is not working

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewmodel

I am developing an app, where users can add their address in their profile and now I want to add a viewModel observer on the coordinates I am receiving from the profile fragment, like my fragment A and give this information to a map fragment, so I can create a new marker on that location. Apparently I am not getting any information of the observer in my fragment B.
So that is my code:

This is the first fragment of the profile:

```
class ProfilFoto : Fragment() {

    lateinit var mDatabase : DatabaseReference
    var mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    var user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
    var DISPLAY_NAME : String? = null
    private var model: Communicator?=null


    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n", "ResourceType")
    override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater,
            container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        //  setContentView(R.layout.fragment_notifications)
        val rootView: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profil_foto, container, false)


        model= activity?.let { ViewModelProviders.of(it).get(Communicator::class.java) }
        
        val loca = rootView.findViewById<View>(R.id.locationtext) as TextView
       
 var uid = user!!.uid

        val userHashMap = HashMap<String, Any>()

        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User").child(uid)

        val speicherButton = rootView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.speichern)



        speicherButton.setOnClickListener {

    
            val location = rootView.findViewById<View>(R.id.locationPerson) as EditText
            

            
            val loc = location.text.toString()
            if (!loc.isEmpty()) {

                Log.e("Location", loc)



                val locationAddress = GeocodingLocation()
                locationAddress.getAddressFromLocation(loc,
                        getActivity()?.getApplicationContext(), GeocoderHandler())

                model!!.setMsgCommunicator(locationAddress.toString())

                //userHashMap["Adresse"] = loc
                mDatabase.child("Adresse").setValue(loc)
                        .addOnSuccessListener {
                            Log.e("Telefon", loc)
                        }
                        .addOnFailureListener {
                            Log.e("Telefon2", "failed")
                        }

                //  mDatabase.updateChildren(userHashMap)
            }

            

    }

mDatabase.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
            }
return rootView
}

private class GeocoderHandler : Handler() {

        override fun handleMessage(message: Message) {

            val locationAddress: String?
            locationAddress = when (message.what) {
                1 -> {
                    val bundle: Bundle = message.getData()
                    bundle.getString("address")
                }
                else -> null
            }
            if (locationAddress != null) {
                Log.e("Handler", locationAddress)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And this is the map fragment where the message should appear:

```
class MapsFragment : Fragment() {

private val callback = OnMapReadyCallback { googleMap ->

 val model= activity?.let { ViewModelProviders.of(it).get(Communicator::class.java) }

        if (model != null) {
            model.message.observe(this, { t ->
                //txt.text = o!!.toString()
                Log.e("Marker", t.toString())
                var latlong = t.toString().split(",")
                var lat = parseFloat(latlong[0])
                var long = parseFloat(latlong[1])

                googleMap.addMarker(
                    MarkerOptions()
                        .position(LatLng(lat.toDouble(), long.toDouble()))
                        .title("Der Neue")
                )
            })
        }

}

override fun onCreateView(
           inflater: LayoutInflater,
           container: ViewGroup?,
           savedInstanceState: Bundle?
   ): View? {

 val rootView : View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_maps, container, false)

...

  return rootView
   }
```

and this is the communicator class I am using:

```
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel

class Communicator : ViewModel(){

    val message =MutableLiveData<Any>()

    fun setMsgCommunicator(msg:String){
        message.setValue(msg)
    }
}
```

and maybe it is important to also show the GeoLocator from where I am getting the coordinates:

```
private const val TAG = "GeocodingLocation"



public class GeocodingLocation  {
    lateinit var mDatabase : DatabaseReference
    var user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser


    fun getAddressFromLocation(locationAddress: String,
                               context: Context?, handler: Handler?) {
        val thread: Thread = object : Thread() {
            override fun run() {

                val geocoder = Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault())
                var result: String? = null
                var uid = user!!.uid
                
                mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User").child(uid)
                try {

                    val addressList: List<*>? = geocoder.getFromLocationName(locationAddress, 1)
                    if (addressList != null && addressList.size > 0) {
                        val address: Address = addressList[0] as Address
                        val sb = StringBuilder()
                        sb.append(address.getLatitude()).append("\n")

                        mDatabase.child("Latitude").setValue(address.latitude)
                                .addOnSuccessListener {
                                    Log.e("Telefon", address.latitude.toString())
                                }
                                .addOnFailureListener {
                                    Log.e("Telefon2", "failed")
                                }
                       
                           
                        sb.append(address.getLongitude()).append("\n")

                        mDatabase.child("Longtitude").setValue(address.longitude)
                                .addOnSuccessListener {
                                    Log.e("Telefon", address.longitude.toString())
                                }
                                .addOnFailureListener {
                                    Log.e("Telefon2", "failed")
                                }

                        result = sb.toString()
                    }
                } catch (e: IOException) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Unable to connect to Geocoder", e)
                } finally {
                    val message: Message = Message.obtain()
                    message.setTarget(handler)
                    if (result != null) {
                        message.what = 1
                        val bundle = Bundle()
                        bundle.putString("address", result)
                        message.setData(bundle)
                    } else {
                        message.what = 1
                        val bundle = Bundle()
                        result = """Address: $locationAddress
 Unable to get Latitude and Longitude for this address location."""
                        bundle.putString("address", result)
                        message.setData(bundle)
                    }
                    message.sendToTarget()
                }

            }
        }
        thread.start()
    }




}
```

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong to get absolutely nothing? Like in the profile fragment I am receiving a latitude and longitude in the Log.

Comment: Move the registering observer code, outside the callback block, inside the callback, set a value when map is ready to update. In the observer check if map is ready, set the marker. Hope that works!

Comment: just as a side note, i believe if `onCancelled` is ever triggered, your app will crash

Comment: and i'm also not entirely sure if `getAddressFromLocation` needs a thread internally, i don't believe it will make much of a difference, but i could be entirely incorrect for each of these

Answer (score 0):

Move the registering observer code, outside the callback block. Inside the callback, set the value when map is ready to update. In the observer check if map is ready, set the marker. Hope that works!

```
private lateinit var googleMap: GoogleMap

private val callback = OnMapReadyCallback { map ->
    googleMap = map
}

val model= activity?.let { ViewModelProviders.of(it).get(Communicator::class.java) }

        

override fun onCreateView(
           inflater: LayoutInflater,
           container: ViewGroup?,
           savedInstanceState: Bundle?
   ): View? {

 val rootView : View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_maps, container, false)

    if (model != null) {
            model.message.observe(this, { t ->
                //txt.text = o!!.toString()
                Log.e("Marker", t.toString())
                var latlong = t.toString().split(",")
                var lat = parseFloat(latlong[0])
                var long = parseFloat(latlong[1])

                googleMap?.let{
                   it.addMarker(
                    MarkerOptions()
                        .position(LatLng(lat.toDouble(), long.toDouble()))
                        .title("Der Neue")
                )
            })
       }
  }

  return rootView
   }
```

Comment: but then it is claiming, that i need a function declaration for the if clause. and if I do so, I still have to call the function in the callback. I did it like this now: `private val callback = OnMapReadyCallback { googleMap ->   val model = activity?.let { ViewModelProviders.of(it).get(Communicator::class.java) }    if (model != null) {
            viewModel(googleMap,model)
        } } `

Comment: and then the function `  fun viewModel(googleMap: GoogleMap, model : Communicator) {
    if (model != null) {
        model.message.observe(this, { t ->
            //txt.text = o!!.toString()
            Log.e("Marker", t.toString())
            var latlong = t.toString().split(",")
            var lat = parseFloat(latlong[0])
            var long = parseFloat(latlong[1])

            googleMap.addMarker(
                MarkerOptions()
                    .position(LatLng(lat.toDouble(), long.toDouble()))
                    .title("Der Neue")
            )
        })
   }
}`

Comment: okay, yes, I did that, thank you, but it still tells me that I can't call the googleMap in the onCreate.

Comment: should I create a new var gMap : GoogleMap in the onCreate?

Comment: No. There was a error from my side. Just add Lamda argument <br/> `googleMap?.let{
                   it.addMarker(
                    MarkerOptions()
                        .position(LatLng(lat.toDouble(), long.toDouble()))
                        .title("Der Neue")
                )`